# How do I add a pause between discord.py messages?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, discord, discord.py

I have a discord bot programmed in python. I want the bot to say the first part of the joke, a time.sleep and then the second part of the joke (both in the same variable). This is my code:

And this is the console output:

Comment: You are adding `time.sleep` in str which returns `None`.

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't be using `time.sleep` at all, as it doesn't play nice with `asyncio`, which `discord.py` is built on.  Instead, we should have a list of pairs, randomly select one, and then use `asyncio.sleep` to pause between messages.:

```
jokes = [
    ('Can a kangaroo jump higher than a house?', 'Of course, a house doesn’t jump at all.'),
    ('Anton, do you think I’m a bad mother?', 'My name is Paul.'),
    ('Why can\'t cats work with a computer?', 'Because they get too distracted chasing the mouse around, haha!'),
    ('My dog used to chase people on a bike a lot.', 'It got so bad, finally I had to take his bike away.'),
    ('What do Italian ghosts have for dinner?', 'Spook-hetti!')]

setup, punchline = random.choice(jokes)
await client.send_message(message.channel, setup)
await asyncio.sleep(3)
await client.send_message(message.channel, punchline)
```

Comment: I do agree with this method more then mine and the other, it gives a method that works well with asyncio

Comment: This is the best answer +1

Answer (score 0):

Your going about it all wrong.

```
a = 'Can a kangaroo jump higher than a house?' + time.sleep(3) + 'Of course, a house doesn’t jump at all.'
```

Will not work, The reason for this is because you want `time.sleep(3)` to be a string, for each of these you would from (what I know). Need to do the following

```
await bot.say("Can a kangaroo jump higher than a house?")
time.sleep(3)
await bot.say('Of course, a house doesn’t jump at all.' )
```

Of course, you would need to change bot to client but this is basically what you have to do.

Reason it wouldn't work:
Doing `a = "string" +func()+"string2 ; print(a)"` would give a error because your treating it all like a string.

Comment: And when I say `You want time.sleep(3) to be a string` I do not mean thats what you should be doing, I mean it as in that  is what you are attempting/ are doing.